# Rstudio rep() and seq()

Tags: r

I need to iterate a sequence that is being repeated. 
Say I have a vector of 1,2,3 I want printed out 5 times.
each time needs to be inceased by one. 
so 1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,5,6,7

Comment: Hi Andrew. Can you include what you have tried so far, and a clear question relating to what you have tried and where it does not work?

Comment: To elaborate on  Jason’s point above. It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rep(1:3, 5) + rep(0:4, each=3)
```

should do the trick